# Not getting the right index from using tag?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have an app where you can add comments to a post. I'm using [sender tag] to get the index but it's always returning the same post. So no matter what post cell I click the comment button on it always adds it to the same cell and not the one I clicked on.

Any help is super appreciated.

Here is my code(note I've stripped my code to only the parts I think will matter to make reading easier as some functions have a lot of code. If you need to see some more just let me know):

Setting the comment button on each cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [cell.commentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(commentButtonClick:) forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];

    return cell; 

    }
```

Comment button. Just performing a segue:

```
- (void)commentButtonClick:(id)sender {

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"addCommentSegue" sender:sender];

}
```

Prepare for segue(I send them to a basic view controller with a text field and a save button):

```
else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"addCommentSegue"]) {

        GFAddCommentViewController *secondDestViewController = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];

        NSInteger index = [sender tag];

        NSDictionary *rootObject = self.posts[index];
        NSDictionary *post = rootObject[@"post"];
        NSDictionary *group = post[@"group"];

        secondDestViewController.postId = [post[@"id"] copy];
        secondDestViewController.groupName =  [group[@"name"] copy];
        secondDestViewController.postBody =[post[@"body"] copy];
    }
```

When they click send on the new view controller this is the function:

```
-(void)addComment:(id)sender {

    GFCredentialStore *credentialStore = [[GFCredentialStore alloc] init];

    NSString * authToken = [credentialStore authToken];

    NSString * addCommentURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s%s/%@/%s", kBaseURL, kPostURL, self.postId, kCommentURL];

    NSString * commentBody = self.commentTextField.text;

    NSMutableDictionary *mutableParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

    if (commentBody) {
        [mutableParams setObject:commentBody forKey:@"comment[body]"];
    }

    [SVProgressHUD showWithStatus:@"Adding Comment"];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:authToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"auth_token"];
    [manager POST:addCommentURL parameters:mutableParams success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
        [SVProgressHUD showSuccessWithStatus:@"Comment Added"];
        [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }]; 

}
```

Just to clarify it's successfully adding comments to the database just the post.id is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you set buttons tag correctly? It seem that you should set like that

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  [cell.commentButton addTarget:self 
                         action:@selector(commentButtonClick:) 
               forControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)UIControlEventTouchDown];
  cell.commentButton.tag = indexPath.row;

  return cell; 

}
```

Comment: Knew I'd forgot something simple. Thanks.